# collapsable menu using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I have created a simple vertical nav bar, which has a some menu items and further each menu item has some sub menu items. When I click on a menu it expands to open its sub menu items and when I click on another menu it also expands.

The problem is that I want one menu item to auto collapse when I click on other menu item, i.e i want only one menu item to be expanded at a time.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default"> 
<div class="container-fluid">   
<ul class="nav nav-list bs-sidenav ">
      <li class="nav-header">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#One"> <font color="grey">Main One</font></a>
        <ul class = "collapse" id = "One">
            <li ><a href="http://Input_Form.jsp"> <font color="grey">Sub One</font></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://2_Input_Form.jsp"><font color="grey">Sub Two</font></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://3_Input_Form.jsp"><font color="grey">Sub Three</font></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
      <li class="nav-header">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Two"> <font color="grey">Main Two</font></a>
        <ul class = "collapse" id = "Two">
            <li ><a href="http://Input_Form.jsp"> <font color="grey">Sub One</font></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://2_Input_Form.jsp"><font color="grey">Sub Two</font></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://3_Input_Form.jsp"><font color="grey">Sub Three</font></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>  
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

use the [collapse plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse).

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried using this but was not sure how to use it with <li> abd <ul> tags

Comment: @Divya do you have a problem with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use `accordion` in bootstrap

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/ciuS71HTga)

```
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible 1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
          <ul>
            <li ><a href="http://Input_Form.jsp"> <font color="grey">Sub One</font></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://2_Input_Form.jsp"><font color="grey">Sub Two</font></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://3_Input_Form.jsp"><font color="grey">Sub Three</font></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible 2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
           <ul>
            <li ><a href="http://Input_Form.jsp"> <font color="grey">Sub One</font></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://2_Input_Form.jsp"><font color="grey">Sub Two</font></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://3_Input_Form.jsp"><font color="grey">Sub Three</font></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is this different from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

## Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ctnels/huwgmn0r/)

And here is the code;

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title"> <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne"> Main One </a> </h4>
        </div>
        <div aria-expanded="false" id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li ><a href="http://Input_Form.jsp"> <font color="grey">Sub One</font></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://2_Input_Form.jsp"><font color="grey">Sub Two</font></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://3_Input_Form.jsp"><font color="grey">Sub Three</font></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <h4 class="panel-title"> <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo"> Main Two </a> </h4>
        </div>
        <div aria-expanded="false" id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li ><a href="http://Input_Form.jsp"> <font color="grey">Sub One</font></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://2_Input_Form.jsp"><font color="grey">Sub Two</font></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://3_Input_Form.jsp"><font color="grey">Sub Three</font></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is very much dealt with still simple css can help you get the desired result.

https://jsfiddle.net/arunzo/dh2zhh2k/

```
nav ul ul {
    display:none;
}

a:focus + ul
{
    display:block;
}
```